# How to browse the file system in WSL 2 in Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I used to be able to access the filesystem of WSL in Windows (such as via File Explorer) via a local file path.

I recently upgraded to WSL 2, and from what I've heard, the file system is on the network. Does anyone know how I could access files from within WSL2 from the Windows side?

Answer (score 17):

Just type in the explorer: `\\wsl$\`

Comment: This did not work - I got the error "Windows cannot access \\wsl$\"

Comment: Works fine for me